# Bootstrap 5 Navbar Position Elements

Tags: css, navbar, bootstrap-5

So I've been boxing with Bootstrap-5 and the "new" way to create a navbar, and I all most got it how I want it. But for some reason I cant seem to get the last element aligned to the right, anyone got some suggestions?

Here is what it looks like now: https://jsfiddle.net/FoTL_Development/428wyt6q/72/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            
            <span class="navbar-toggler">Brand Name</span> <!-- Get the hide/apper effect but without the style -->
            <!-- Left Element -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Left Element -->

            <!-- Center Element -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 m-auto">
                <li>Center</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Center Element -->

            <!-- Right Element -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li>Right</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Right Element -->

          </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `ms-auto` to push the last element to the right...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <span class="navbar-toggler">Brand Name</span> <!-- Get the hide/apper effect but without the style -->
        <!-- Left Element -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- End Left Element -->
        <!-- Center Element -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 m-auto">
                <li>Center</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- End Center Element -->
        <!-- Right Element -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li>Right</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- End Right Element -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://codeply.com/p/y2YCYHmcYQ

Also it appears you have an unnecessary `me-auto` on the center nav.